# Graph plotting in pandas and seaborn

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I have the table with 5 columns with 8000 rows:

```
   Market   DeliveryWindowID    #Orders   #UniqueShoppersAvailable      #UniqueShoppersFulfilled

    NY         296              2               2                               5
    MA         365              3               4                               8
```

How do I plot a graph in pandas or seaborn that will show the #Order, #UniqueShoppersAvailable,     #UniqueShoppersFulfilled v/s the market and delivery window?

Comment: I want to have marketName and DeliveryWindowID together. I need to find the number of orders, number of shoppers and number of shoppers available for each market name and delivery window id.

Answer (score 1):

One  way is to set Market as index forcing it onto the x axis and do a bar graph if you wanted a quick visualization. This can be stacked or not.

Not Stacked

```
import matplotlib .pyplot as plt
df.drop(columns=['DeliveryWindowID']).set_index(df.Market).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Stacked

```
   df.drop(columns=['DeliveryWindowID']).set_index(df.Market).plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: I want to have marketName and DeliveryWindowID together. I need to find the number of orders, number of shoppers and number of shoppers available for each market name and delivery window id.

Comment: What do you mean together? Try `df.groupby(['Market','DeliveryWindowID']).agg(Orders=('#Orders','sum'),UniqueShoppersAvailable=('#UniqueShoppersAvailable','sum'),UniqueShoppersFulfilled=('#UniqueShoppersFulfilled','sum')).unstack().plot(kind='bar')`

Comment: @Scott Boston, I thought so, thats why I dropped it in the initial code

Answer (score 1):

Using Seaborn, reshape your dataframe with `melt` first:

```
df_chart = df.melt(['Market','DeliveryWindowID'])
sns.barplot('Market', 'value',hue='variable', data=df_chart)
```

Output:

[image]